# UIViewController trying call handleKeyEvent: method when app starts

Tags: ios, objective-c

When application starts, if `rootViewController` selected in a storyboard or if I set it by code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, it is not matter, application crashes, because it is trying to call method `handleKeyEvent:`

Here `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (!self.window) {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = (LoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    if (self.window.rootViewController) {
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController
                                                 animated:NO
                                               completion:nil];
    } else if (![self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:loginViewController.class]) {
        [self.window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

And here is console output:

```
2016-02-11 13:17:56.685 Project[820:201184] -[LoginViewController handleKeyEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166add30
2016-02-11 13:17:56.689 Project[820:201184] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController handleKeyEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166add30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x24afc10b 0x242a2e17 0x24b01925 0x24aff559 0x24a2fc08 0x28c39471 0x28cafd3f 0x28caf89f 0x28ed8f9d 0x28cacebd 0x28ed7d81 0x28eebb9d 0x28ed53ab 0x25de0c7f 0x25de0f71 0x24abf68f 0x24abf27d 0x24abd5eb 0x24a10bf9 0x24a109e5 0x28ca65bd 0x28ca0ba1 0xe068d 0x246bf873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

May be someone knows what happens?

**UPDATE:**

It seems it was an iOS bug. After restart of a device all start working well.

Comment: Please show me your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = (LoginViewController *)          [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        if (self.window.rootViewController) {
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController
                                                     animated:NO
                                                   completion:nil];
        } else if (![self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:loginViewController.class]) {
            [self.window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
        }

       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;
    }
```